Lambda Function issue with http post request
I have created a Lambda function on AWS written in Python.  This function is to be the middleman to receive my outgoing webhook from Cradlepoint NetCloud Manager and then pass the specific pieces of the payload that I want to my Teams channel as an incoming webhook.  I had to create this function since NetCloud Manager requires you to input a secret key and on Teams, there's no way to set that up for an incoming webhook.  I am able to get this to be fully functional, but not in the desired way.
I'll include the code I've written below.  This is the way I want it to work and this code will parse out the data that I need and wish to forward to Teams.  For some reason doing it this way, I get no errors, and when testing from Postman sending a sample JSON payload that NetCloud Manager would send for an alert, it returns a status code 200 and accepts the request, but it doesn't make it to Teams.  I have a return statement of the dictionary named myobj just so I can see from Postman that I have parsed the data correctly in which I have done.  If I create myobj as a dictionary such as {'text': data1} for instance and send the post request that way, it is successful but the way it appears in Teams is not very readable for the average non-tech person in my company that would be interested in this alert.  See the code below and please offer some advice on how I can only pass the relevant data that I have parsed over to Teams.  Thanks.
import json
import requests
import hmac
import os

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    body = event["body"] or " "
    headers = event["headers"]
    ret = 200
    secret = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
    h = hmac.new(secret.encode("utf-8"), body.encode("utf-8"), "sha256")
    signature = h.hexdigest()
    
    if secret != headers["x-cp-signature"]:    
        ret = 403
    else:
        ret = 200   

    myobj = {}
    data1 = json.loads(body)
    body1 = json.loads(event['body'])
    
    # parse out relevant data
    whatType = body1['data'][0]['type']
    friendlyInfo = body1['data'][0]['friendly_info']
    routerDetails = body1['data'][0]['router_details']['name']
    macAddress = body1['data'][0]['router_details']['mac']
    
    # gathers additional parsed data for this type of alert
    if whatType == 'pdp_router_overage':
        carrierName = body1['data'][0]['info']['data_plan']['carrier_name']
        dataLimit = body1['data'][0]['info']['data_plan']['data_limit']
        billingCycleStart = body1['data'][0]['info']['data_plan']['billing_cycle_day']
        actualUsage = body1['data'][0]['info']['actual_usage']
        myobj = {
                'Router Details:  ': routerDetails,
                'MAC Address:  ': macAddress,
                'Type:  ': whatType,
                'Info:  ': friendlyInfo,
                'Carrier:  ': carrierName,
                'Data Limit:  ': dataLimit,
                'Actual Usage:  ':  str(actualUsage),
                'Billing Cycle Start Day:  ': str(billingCycleStart)
        }
    else:
        myobj = {
            'Router Details:  ': routerDetails,
            'MAC Address:  ': macAddress,
            'Type:  ': whatType,
            'Info:  ': friendlyInfo
        }   
    
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
    
    teams = requests.post(os.environ.get('TEAMS_URL'), data=json.dumps(myobj), headers=headers)
    return(myobj)


    

